# Code Styling in phpStorm: from if(a==b){ to if (a == b) { on Enter, is it possible?

Tags: phpstorm

In phpStorm, when I type:

```php
if(a==b){
```

(no spaces), and I push "Enter", is the any possibilities (settings/configurations) to phpStorm automatically reformat that code to:

```php
if ( a == b ) {
    //cursor now here
    }
???
```

According to "Code Style" settings (rules) it SHOULD reformat, but it does not!
(if I manually select the code and do "reformat code" - then it does! But I think it should be automatically done on Enter for just-typed string of code)

phpStorm v. 2.1

Comment: Relatively certain it doesn't format on carriage returns, just on paste (if you have it enabled) and when you manually instruct it to reformat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand the question when replying the first time. Now I see the the problem is not about indent, but about spaces around the parenthesis.

This behavior is by design, such spaces are not inserted on <kbd>Enter</kbd>, they are only inserted when you reformat code (or when you paste code and automatic reformat on paste is enabled).

Comment: Settings are the same. It DOES indent and  also it puts '}' BUT it doesn't put spaces... (language PHP)

Comment: Did you check the video? It does put the spaces. Try 3.0 version.